# $http request returns data only if I wrap inside a $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have a problem here, whenever I am clicking the button which is inside the component, I see that I am making the $http call and I don't get the response in the console, but in browser I see the call is made.

It consoles the data only when I uncomment the $timeout function.

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', [$scope, $http, $timeout, function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

   $scope.navigate = function () {
      $scope.getStats();
   }

   $scope.getStats = function () {
      //$timeout(function () {
            $http
                .get('/scripts/controllers/fda/appSvc.json')
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
     //}, 0)
   };

    $scope.detailedTableCtrl = {
        navigate: $scope.navigate
    }

}]);

app.component("myBox",  {
      bindings: {
            'detailedTableCtrl': '='
        },
      controller: function($element) {

      },
      controllerAs: 'myBox',
      templateUrl: "/template",
      transclude: true
})
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <my-box detailed-table-ctrl="detailedTableCtrl"></my-box>
    </div><!--end app-->

<!--mybox component-->
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="myBox.detailedTableCtrl.navigate()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span>Back</span>
            </button>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're injecting `$http`

Comment: Or `$timeout` for that matter!

Comment: I forgot to add it here in the question, but I am injecting both $http and $timeout

Answer (score 0):

As @Amy pointed out i don't see $http service injected. Also please do use service to consume data and inject the service in controller. Your controller shouldn't worry about calling/consuming data.

```
<!-- Controller to get data from the Service or Factory ( pay attention to service injection here ) -->
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope,dataService) {

   dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
            $scope.response = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
            $scope.response = [];
        });
});

<!-- Factory to handle your data from REST or JSON -->
(function () {
    "use strict";
    app.factory("dataService",['$http', function($http){

    function getData (){  
       return $http.get('/scripts/controllers/fda/appSvc.json');
    }
    return {
        getData : getData
    };
}]);
})();
```

Comment: I forgot to add it here in the question, but I am injecting both $http and $timeout.  The problem I am facing is the $http request is made. I got the response in the browser, but `.then` function is not called. It is getting  called only when I wrap in `$timeout`